# Assign an entire row to multiple rows of another matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a 13 by 3 matrix called face.

```
face =

     1     1     1
     1     1     1
     1     0     0
     1     1     1
     1     1     1
     1     0     0
     1     0     0
     1     1     1
     1     1     1
     1     1     1
     1     1     1
     0     0     0
     0     0     0
```

And I have an array newset1, which contains the indices of the rows of the matrix 'face' which have to be assigned a new value.

```
newset1 = [5,1,7]
```

The "new value" is a vector shown below

```
value = [7,8,9]
```

I know how to access the rows whose values should be updated. Like this : 
   face(newset1,:)

```
ans =

     1     1     1
     1     1     1
     1     0     0
```

And I want to do something like this

```
face(newset1,:) = value
```

And have my output look like this :

```
face =

     7     8     9
     1     1     1
     1     0     0
     1     1     1
     7     8     9
     1     0     0
     7     8     9
     1     1     1
     1     1     1
     1     1     1
     1     1     1
     0     0     0
     0     0     0
```

But I get the following error.

> Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

It makes sense to me, what I'm doing, but since it doesn't work, I am pretty sure that I'm wrong. I'd also prefer not to use a for-loop, because I've read that matlab slows down on loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using repmat() function. See here: [MATLAB: duplicating vector 'n' times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10316128/matlab-duplicating-vector-n-times).

Your desired output is achievable by

```
face(newset1,:)=repmat(value,length(newset1),1)
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. It works perfectly. And I looked it up right now. I'm guessing that it basically replicates the row value like this >> repmat(value,length(newset1),1)

ans =

     7     8     9
     7     8     9
     7     8     9 And then it assigns it to the rows I need it. Once again, thanks!!

Comment: And the repmat function does not use loops, so you won't slow down.

Comment: That's good news :) I've become so used to using loops that my matlab program takes forever to run. So now I'm in the process of rewriting everything, getting rid of as many loops I can. Once again, Thanks :)

Comment: @TinaMaria Please accept the answer if it anwsered your question. That way other people will know this question have a good answer.

Comment: @TinaMaria Few more ways to replicate data are described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22847086/how-to-replicate-an-array)