# How to efficiently construct a matrix in matlab that depends on indices

Tags: matlab, matrix-multiplication, elementwise-operations

In my program in matlab I have several instances where I need to create a matrix, which entries depends on its indices and perform matrix-vector operations with it. I wonder how I can implement this most efficiently.

For example, I need to speed up:

```
N = 1e4;
x = rand(N,1);

% Option 1
tic
I = 1:N;
J = 1:N;
S = zeros(N,N);
for i = 1:N
    for j = 1:N
        S(i,j) = (i+j)/(abs(i-j)+1);
    end
end
a = x'*S*x
fprintf('Option 1 takes %.4f sec\n',toc)
clearvars -except x N
```

I try to speed this up, so I have tried the following options:

```
% Option 2
tic
I = 1:N;
J = 1:N;
Sx = zeros(N,1);
for i = 1:N
    Srow_i = (i+J)./(abs(i-J)+1);
    Sx(i)= Srow_i*x;
end
a = x'*Sx
fprintf('Option 2 takes %.4f sec\n',toc)
clearvars -except x N
```

and

```
% Option 3
tic
I = 1:N;
J = 1:N;
S = bsxfun(@plus,I',J)./(abs(bsxfun(@minus,I',J))+1);
a = x'*S*x
fprintf('Option 3 takes %.4f sec\n',toc)
clearvars -except x N
```

and (thanks to one of the answers)

```
% options 4
tic
[I , J] = meshgrid(1:N,1:N);
S = (I+J) ./ (abs(I-J) + 1);
a = x' * S * x;
fprintf('Option 4 takes %.4f sec\n',toc)
clearvars -except x N
```

Otion 2 is the most efficient. Is there a faster option of doing this operation?

**Update:**

I have also tried the option by Abhinav:

```
% Option 5 using Tony's Trick
tic
i = 1:N;
j = (1:N)';
I = i(ones(N,1),:);
J = j(:,ones(N,1));
S = (I+J)./(abs(I-J)+1);
a = x'*S*x;
fprintf('Option 5 takes %.4f sec\n',toc)
clearvars -except x N
```

It seems that the most efficient procedure depends on the size of N. For different N I get the following output:

N = 100:

```
Option 1 takes 0.00233 sec
Option 2 takes 0.00276 sec
Option 3 takes 0.00183 sec
Option 4 takes 0.00145 sec
Option 5 takes 0.00185 sec
```

N = 10000:

```
Option 1 takes 3.29824 sec
Option 2 takes 0.41597 sec
Option 3 takes 0.72224 sec
Option 4 takes 1.23450 sec
Option 5 takes 1.27717 sec
```

So, for small N, option 2 is the slowest but it becomes the most efficient for larger N. Maybe because of memory? Could somebody explain this?

Comment: are you only interested by the value of `a` ?

Comment: I included the computation of a to do a fair comparison, because it is slightly different in option 2.

Answer (score 2):

You can create indices using meshgrid and no need to loop:

```
N = 1e4;
[I , J] = meshgrid(1:N,1:N);
x = rand(N,1);
S = (I+J) ./ (abs(I-J) + 1);
a = x' * S * x;
```

**Update:**

Since @Optimist shown that performance of this code is less than Option2 and Option3 I decided to slightly improve Option2:

```
N = 1e4;
x = rand(N,1);
Sx = zeros(N,1);
for i = 1:N
    Srow_i = (i+1:i+N)./[i:-1:2,1:N-i+1] ;
    Sx(i)= Srow_i*x;
end
a = x'*Sx;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This avoids indeed a for loop, but is unfortunately less efficient than both option 2 and 3.

Comment: @Optimist usually I think that loop leads to less efficient code, but your example shown that if loop used correctly can lead to increased efficiency. I updated my answer and slightly modify your option2.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using the [Tony's trick](http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~marios/matlab/Matlab%20Tricks.pdf) to do vector stacking/tiling in Matlab the fastest way. I have answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10327626/842808). Here is the `Tony's Trick` option.

```
% Option using Tony's Trick
tic
i = 1:N;
j = (1:N)';
I = i(ones(N,1),:);
J = j(:,ones(N,1));
S = (I+J)./(abs(I-J)+1);

a = x'*S*x
fprintf('Option 1 takes %.4f sec\n',toc)
```

Edit 1: I ran a few tests and found the following. Up to N=1000, the `Tony's trick` option is slightly faster than the `Option 2`. Beyond that, `Option 2` again catches up and becomes faster.

Possible Reason :
This should be so because, up until the size of the array could fit in the cache, the fully vectorized code (`Tony's Trick option`) is faster BUT as soon as the array sizes grow (N>1000), it spills into memory caches away from the CPU and then Matlab uses some internal optimization to breakdown the `Tony's Trick` code into piecemeal code so that it no-longer enjoys the benefit of complete vectorization.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have tried your option and indeed it performs faster than option 2 for smaller N (e.g. N=200). In that case option 4 turns out to be the fastest. For larger N, option 2 outperforms the rest. Your explanation sounds reasonable.