# Fast expansion of category values to rows of normalised feature vector in a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave, categorical-data

I am looking for an efficient, vectorised way to expand a column vector of category numbers into a matrix of normalised features.

For example, I might have:

```
octave:16> false_vals
false_vals =

  -0.10000  -0.20000  -0.50000

octave:17> true_vals
true_vals =

   0.90000   0.80000   0.50000

octave:18> cats
cats =

   1
   2
   3
```

And I would like to combine them to create a matrix where each row was the same as `false_vals` but with the index position identified by `cats` set to the corresponding value from `true_vals`. For the example, that would look like this:

```
octave:19> X
X =

   0.90000  -0.20000  -0.50000
  -0.10000   0.80000  -0.50000
  -0.10000  -0.20000   0.50000
```

I found [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459851/octave-matlab-extend-a-vector-making-it-repeat-itself) that I can extend to give me a random allocation:

```
octave:28> X = repmat(false_vals,3,1)
X =

  -0.10000  -0.20000  -0.50000
  -0.10000  -0.20000  -0.50000
  -0.10000  -0.20000  -0.50000

octave:29> Y = repmat(true_vals,3,1)
Y =

   0.90000   0.80000   0.50000
   0.90000   0.80000   0.50000
   0.90000   0.80000   0.50000

octave:30> L = ( rand(3,3) > 0.5 ) % This stands in for the actual logical matrix I want
L =

   1   1   1
   1   1   1
   0   0   1

octave:31> X(L) = Y(L)
X =

   0.90000   0.80000   0.50000
   0.90000   0.80000   0.50000
  -0.10000  -0.20000   0.50000
```

But I am then stuck on how to replace the `rand` above with some function that can turn my `cats` vector into

```
L = 
 1  0  0
 0  1  0
 0  0  1
```

I.e. I know I can do what I want with a logical matrix, but don't know how to get from my vector `cats` to the correct logical matrix (for each row of `L`, column position identified by value of that row in `cats` vector should be true, so I can use it in the last statement).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can repeat the row with [`repmat`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) and then replace the desired values using [linear indexing](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html):

```
n = numel(cats);
result = repmat(false_vals, n, 1); %// repeat row n times
result((cats.'-1)*n+(1:n)) = true_vals; %'// replace desired values
```

Comment: This works for that L being stated, but I think OP's general case requirement was for a rand based solution. +1 for a good starting point!

Comment: OK, got it, the linear indexing is row first, which really confused me for a while.

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

```
N = 3; %// size of false_vals and true_vals

%// Expand false_vals to create X
X = repmat(false_vals,N,1)

%// Find linear indices for expanded matrix, where true_vals are to be put
%// For this, you would need two things - row and column indices.
%// 1. Row indices would be just [1:N], as we are looking to get one replacement
%// per row.
%// 2. Column indices would be either of 1 or 2 or .. N
ind = round((N-1)*rand(1,N)) %// ind would be column indices minus 1
true_vals_idx = N*ind+[1:N] %// [1:N] represent the row indices

%// Replace the elements at those linearly indexed positions with true_vals 
X(true_vals_idx) = true_vals
```

If along with the earlier criteria of one replacement per row, you would also like to have one replacement per column, you can modify the `ind` calculation part a bit like so -

```
%// Create unique numbers for the interval [1,N], which could also be calculated with 
%// randperm, but that being slow has been replaced by a sort-based implementation
[~,ind] = sort(rand(N,1)) 
true_vals_idx = N*(ind-1)+[1:N]

%// .. Rest of the code stays the same
```

Note: The sort based implementation to "re-create" randperm was based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25231333/3293881).

Comment: This is useful, and includes the answer I need, but I may have made things more complex by mentioning `rand()`. I am using it in my question to stand in for "I know I need a logical matrix here, but don't know how to create the correct one from `cats`" - I will edit and try to make clearer.

Comment: @NeilSlater If that's the case, Luis's solution has to be the most efficient one.